# React App S3 Hosting, Url Paramters not working on S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static, hosting

I have a route saying /project/:id, When I try to navigate to project/42 in S3 static hosting it just crashes my app

UDPATE: When I try'n navigate to that with the help of an interactive button  and then push it to say if the route is project/:id then through button I pushed it to project/42, That works perfectly. But if I enter the route in browser URL it's just giving me a white page or a reload on that is also giving me a white page

Comment: "crashes my app" can you give more details or provide a screenshot? Apps can crash for many reasons

Comment: Updated the question, Please help

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

in your s3 bucket you need to enter `index.html` where it says `error.html`

like this:

[image]

Comment: I've already done this and it only works for where there are no URL parameters kind of routes like just normal /projects, For routes like this it works on reload or URL enter through the browser but for routes having URL parameters like /projects/:id it just gives me a white page on reload or Url enter to that route through the browser, I also tried Cloudfront error page redirection but it didn't work. Please help.